# How to explode a multi-line string?

Tags: php, explode

I have a string that has different values on each line:

```
$matches="value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
";
```

I want to explode the whole string in to an array consisting of the values separeted. I know how to explode a space separated string, like `explode(' ', $matches)`. But how do i use the explode function on this type of string?

I tried this:

```
$matches=explode('\n',$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But the result is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello

)
```

Comment: Which OS you are using? Different OS' have different new line characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to change `'\n'` to `"\n"`.

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

> If the string is enclosed in
>   double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret
>   more escape sequences for special
>   characters:
>
> \n    linefeed (LF or 0x0A (10) in ASCII)
>   [More...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 6):

Read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Note:  Unlike the double-quoted and
>   heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape
>   sequences for special characters will
>   not be expanded when they occur in
>   single quoted strings.

So use "\n" instead of '\n'

Also, instead of `\n` you can use PHP_EOL constant.
In the Windows "\r\n" can be used as end of line, for this case you can make double replacement:
`$matches=explode("\n", str_replace("\r","\n",$matches));`