# Exploding array for url

Tags: php, arrays, parse-url

I'm developing a site for analyzing a store's data.
I need the url part of my array to look like this:

```
array(
    'url'       => 'http://some.website.com:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_username=user-123',
    '_password' => 'passwd',
    '_program'  => '/Utilisateurs/DARTIES3-2012/Mon dossier/analyse_dc',
    'annee'     => '2012',
    'ind'       => 'V',
    '_action'   => 'execute'
);
```

I currently have this and am struggling to convert it to the desired format:

```
array(
    'url' => 'url=http://some.website.com:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_username=user-123&_password=passwd&_program=%2FUtilisateurs%2FDARTIES3-2012%2FMon+dossier%2Fanalyse_dc&annee=2012&ind=V&_action=execute',
    'otherKey' => 'otherValue'
);
```

Please can somebody help me to convert the URL in the second code block to look like the first code block? Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: You shouldnt be passing passwords in the URL

Comment: You can do a foreach ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162912/how-to-explode-a-multi-line-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this will extract the url in the form you want, as `$url`:

```
$myArray = array(
    'url' => 'url=http://some.website.com:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_username=user-123&_password=passwd&_program=%2FUtilisateurs%2FDARTIES3-2012%2FMon+dossier%2Fanalyse_dc&annee=2012&ind=V&_action=execute',
    'otherKey' => 'otherValue'
);
parse_str($myArray['url']);
echo $url;
```

You will need to decide where it needs to go next and how you get it there.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use: [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) over your `$array['url']`